# How to clear the bad sectors from harddisk?

Tags: debian, hard-drive

I am using debain 6 in my system, Recently the dekstop frequently hangs. So, when i look on the harddisk health i have find a lot of bad sector. So, can anyone say to remove the bad sector of harddisk of live system.[image]

Comment: Never mind the sectors, replace the entire drive.

Comment: They're already removed. That's what "reallocated" means.

Comment: You [go to Seagate to verify if the drive is still in warranty](http://support.seagate.com/customer/en-US/warranty_validation.jsp?form=1). If it is, Seagate sends you a replacement. If not, you go to the shop and buy a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, the controller/disk utility (`chkdsk` in Windows, `badblocks` in NIX) will detect bad blocks/sectors and mark them as unreadable/writable, but there's always the risk of data loss if it's not detected and dealt with in time.

However in this day and age of commodity hardware, you remove the bad sectors by replacing the hard drive as soon as they're detected and safe to do so.  There's really no other way to be ensure data integrity and/or system stability at that point.